# <c:forEach not rendering with tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces, jstl

I am using tomcat 7 while my coworkers are on 6 and we are trying to run this type of structure:

```
<c:forEach>
    <rich:panelMenuGroup>
        <c:forEach>
            <rich:panelMenuItem>
            </rich:panelMenuItem>
        </c:forEach>
    </rich:panelMenuGroup>
</c:forEach>
```

Any advice would be appreciate if there is a workaround or something like that it's fine as well because we WILL be moving to 7 and need a way to get this to work.

thanks

Comment: Are all the jars available in your tomcat 7 installation?

Comment: Yes like I said it works perfectly on a co workers the only difference is tomcat 7 but I think Jigar Joshi's answer should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat doesn't ship with JSTL. The JSTL JARs are normally provided by `/WEB-INF/lib` of the webapp, but sometimes the JARs are just dropped straight in Tomcat's own `/lib` folder so that it get applied to all webapps without them to have JSTL in their `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Apparently the old Tomcat 6 server had JSTL in its `/lib` and the webapp is built without JSTL in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

You need to ensure that Tomcat 7 has also JSTL in its `/lib`, or you just need to drop JSTL in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/lib`.